# Java - Interface members' value

Tags: java, class, interface

When I have a class that implements an interface , will all objects of that class have the same value of the members in the interface?

i.e

```
interface I {
 int element = 10;//since its public static final by default
 String s = "abcd"; 
}



class A implements I {
  private int timer;
  ...
  public void setTimer(int timer) {
      this.timer = timer
  }
}
```

So assume there are 3 objects of `A` namely`a1,a2,a3`

All object's value of `element` and `s` will be `10` and `abcd` respectively right?

Is it possible to change it?(like by casting A to I). But it is not possible to create an object of A with different value of `element and s`..

Clarify me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I have a class that implements an interface , will all objects of that class have the same value of the members in the interface?

Yes. The classes that implement an interface will inherit every interface's members.

> All object's value of element and s will be 10 and abcd respectively right?

Yes.

> Is it possible to change it?

You can't change the value of a `final` variable, but if you want `element` (for example) to hold a different value in different context, then you can *hide* it. For example, you can introduce another variable, called `element`, which holds another value:

```
interface A {
    int x = 10;
}

class B implements A {
    static int x = 5;
    void test() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Here, the `B.x` variable *hides* the `A.x` constant. If you omit the `int x = 5` declaration, then the `System.out.println(x)` will print the constant in the `A` interface.

Comment: Is it possible to cast `bObject` to type `A` such that A.x has 5?                       B bObject = new B();    bObject.x = 15;   A a = (A)bObject;   such that a.x=15?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly valid. But, since these members are `static` you don't actually need instances. If you need A's `x` member, just do `A.x` (or `B.x`, for the other one).

Comment: But when I cast it still has its old value. http://ideone.com/rUB6Gh. I expected `i.element` to be 2 and not 10 after casting

Comment: In your example `a` is cast and copied to `i`. `a` doesn't change, but `i` is something different. :)

Comment: Is it possible that `element` be only in `I` and the class that implements it redefines the value of `element`? i.e each object of `A` having different value of element?

Comment: As I explained, no. The element in `I` is `final` and thus, **can not** be changed, but **can** be *hidden*. Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: In your previous comment you said `i is something different`. can you explain a bit on that?

Comment: `i` is another variable (different than `a`), which value is a  "copy of `a` cast to `I`".

Answer (score 0):

Interface is meant for static final variables. If you want to change variable value in interface implemented classes (overriding instead of hiding), it is better to go for abstract class and protected variables.